# Quickly adding multiple items to an UICollectionView fails

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, uicollectionview

I've got this `UICollectionView` set up with a fetched results controller, using core data. I use `UIImagePickerController` to add items to the `UICollectionView`. Now when I tap one of the photos stored on my device, it will be added to my managed object context and will be inserted into the `UICollectionView`.

Now when I quickly add multiple items, the app crashes with the following error:

```
2012-10-07 13:17:46.770 PhotoLibrary[2444:907] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2372/UICollectionView.m:2801
```

It seems like it can't handle adding an item while the animation of the previous added item hasn't ended yet. Just happens when you add them really quickly, but some of the users will do that.

Is there a good way to just wait and add the item when the other one is finished? Users should be able to add them "real time", so I can't just run all the changes at once.

Comment: I'm getting this problem, too-- can't for the life of me figure out how to simply (1) detect that animation is happening, so that (2) I can wait until its completion to call the next update method.

Comment: If I call any of the update methods other than `reloadData` (which seems to always work) I get this exception. I don't want to rely on `reloadData` though, since that will re-add / redraw all content, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error only occurred when adding a few items quickly. But the real problem wasn't really related to the animation. I was creating the managed objects used to store the new items in a block, used in the `ALAssetsLibrary`'s `assetForURL:resultBlock:` method.

Took a while to figure out that that was the problem, the managed objects were created in a separate thread. Turns out that managed objects doesn't handle that well.

Now moved the creation of the new items outside of the block, now it just works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Without example code, I'm presuming the problem occurs when calling the `- (void)reloadData` method after inserting data into the `UICollectionView`.  The documentation for this method explicitly calls out the fact you shouldn't call this method in the middle of an animation caused by insertion/deletion since the insertion/deletion will invoke the animation code automatically.

Some other notable methods are `- (void)insertItemsAtIndexPath:(NSArray *)indexPaths` and `- (void)performBatchUpdates:(void (^)(void))updates completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion`.  I have not used the batch method, but I've used the insert method a number of times and it works well.